# Ubuntu - var file taking up all my space

Tags: 20.04

After dual-booting Ubuntu with my Windows machine recently I have found myself to be almost out of space. I allocated a partition of 200G so wasn't expecting this to happen - looks like it's something to do with my log file, using 176G of this space.

I've had a brief look through and the syslog files look to be a particular issue so assume there is some sort of error which keeps writing to these files. Being relatively new to Linux I'm not entirely sure what the error is or how to fix it. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/a/935307/1609639 Maybe this can help you with your problem.

Comment: "Some sort of error" requires "some sort of fix" .... If you want help, you should update your question with examples of the error from the syslog file.

Comment: You could start by pasting the contents of the last hour from your `/var/log/syslog` file - if so much data is written, it will certainly be some repeated entry that is easy to spot.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I free up space of var](https://askubuntu.com/questions/935245/how-do-i-free-up-space-of-var)